# Identify multiple images present on page with userscript?

Tags: jquery, userscripts

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = ("https://website.com/images/a.jpg")

if (image.width == 0) {
  alert("image not present");
} else {
    alert("image is present");
}
```

This is working just for image a.jpg

I want userscript to alert when any of these images found on the page a.jpg or b.jpg or c.jpg

I tired jquary OR operator like this but not working

image.src = ("https://website.com/images/a.jpg" ||  [https://website.com/images/b.jpg"](https://website.com/images/b.jpg%22))

Looking for a way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you could add your image urls to an array and iterate through that array

```
const prefix = "https://website.com/images/";
const imagesFiles = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg","c.jpg"];


imageFiles.forEach(fileName => {
   const image = new Image();
   image.src = prefix + fileName;
   if(image.width == 0){
      alert("image not present");
    } else {
      alert("image is present");
    }
});
```

But I am not sure if this solves your problem, because I am not sure if Image() will throw an error on 404. And I think you will need to add an event handler to image, because loading an image is an asynchronous task.

Further reading:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: This is not working  

`const prefix = "https://site.to/images/";`  
`const imagesFiles = ["/april/u/x/3/ux3kxcfs21fn.mid.jpg", "may/d/e/4/de4fwlzlohkz.mid.jpg","c.jpg"];`